# Using local resources in silver light

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I need to know if there is an option to use local resources in my silver light 4 application and if there any restrictions . I mean saving file or reading from hard drive , connecting local SQL express , connecting serial port , ...
Are there any tutorials .
Thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight is specifically designed to not allow access to the user's computer.

You can only access the user's hard drive through an `OpenFileDialog` or a `SaveFileDialog`.  You will not know the name or path of the file using this method. Additionally, these dialogs must be displayed by a "user generated action", which is typically a button click or some other UI interaction.

Databases, ports, and pretty much anything else is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You are allowed to edit items in Isolated storage. You can create items/files and access them in your Silverlight app.

Here is tutorial on how to use it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bdts8hk0(v=vs.95).aspx